# Not able to set Origin in request header in WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an iOS app centred around a WKWebView loading local web assets with loadFileURL. The WKWebView communicates over HTTPS to a backend API. We have made some changes at back end and due to that we need to send some app specific values for Origin of request header. In case my case value is getting replace by some default value as file://. I'm getting CORS issue while loading my application.

Can I change the origin of the WKWebView to xyz to avoid browsers from querying the API?

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.setValue(true, forKey: "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: config)
view.addSubview(webView)
if let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") {
    let htmlURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath)
    var request = URLRequest(url: htmlURL)
    webView.load(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom URLRequest and load that request into the WKWebView.

```
import WebKit

// Create a WKWebView
let webView = WKWebView()

// Create a custom URLRequest
if let url = URL(string: "https://example.com") {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    // Set the 'Origin' header in the request
    request.setValue("https://your-origin-url.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Origin")
    
    // Load the custom request in the WKWebView
    webView.load(request)
}
```

Comment: I want to load index.html file from my bundled resource. I do not want to load a remote server URL.